# Quantization Step Size or Quantization factor

Tags: signals, signal-processing, quantization

About non-linear Quantization techniques:
we have the "QIM" (Quantization Index Modulation).
This technique use some quantizers of step size (quantization factor) delta in order to quantize samples of original signal.
That i noticed after my researches about quantization step size, that this last can be small or large.

```
--Increasing the quantization step size to be coarse decreases the amount of encoded data, and also degrades the quality of the reconstructed picture. For images having a lot of information, degradation in quality is a serious problem.

--Decreasing the quantization step size to be fine increases the amount of encoded data, and also reduces degradation in the quality of the reconstructed picture. For images having little information, degradation in quality is not such a serious problem, and reduction in the amount of encoded data is desirable.

--Thus, it is seen that to select the optimum quantization step size, it is necessary to consider picture quality as well as buffer occupancy.
```

After that, i have two questions:

1) What is the range values of quantization step size?

2) It is possible to set 0.1 as quantization step size value in order to obtain a very low distortion?

Best regards,

Liszt

Comment: Probably better suited for [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com)

Comment: For whatever moderator looks at this, there should really be an 'Other' option when recommending migration to another stack exchange site